# Installing nodejs on wordpress docker image - node: not found

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to install nodejs and npm onto a docker image, based from the official wordpress image, ultimately to install gulp.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install gulp
```

When I build the image, it appears to install nodejs, but then fail on something

> Setting up nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ... update-alternatives: using
>   /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
>   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of
>   /usr/share/man/man1/js.1.gz because associated file
>   /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz (of link group js) doesn't exist

and ultimately, I get the following error

> /bin/sh: 1: node: not found

I can't work out why this would be?

The full output from the build log is below

```
Building wordpress
Step 1/6 : FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
 ---> 18747ca95580
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 8b7c3e8d34d6
Ign:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [5148 B]
Get:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7099 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [385 kB]
Fetched 7794 kB in 3s (1984 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 8b7c3e8d34d6
 ---> 1bcbd1ee66ef
Step 3/6 : RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in 9b732a5af611
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libuv1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libuv1 nodejs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3524 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libuv1 amd64 1.9.1-3 [84.4 kB]
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 nodejs amd64 4.8.2~dfsg-1 [3440 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 3524 kB in 1s (2812 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libuv1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 13068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuv1_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_4.8.2~dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Setting up nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/js.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz (of link group js) doesn't exist
Removing intermediate container 9b732a5af611
 ---> bbf198ce7820
Step 4/6 : RUN node -v
 ---> Running in 39269d307aa6
/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
```

**UPDATE**

My docker file now looks like this

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN nodejs -v
RUN npm -v
```

Running this with `docker build . --no-cache` results in the below output.

Summary: Node is v4.8.2, and npm is not found

```
Step 1/6 : FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
 ---> 18747ca95580
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 9bcb0285ff3f
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [5148 B]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [386 kB]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7099 kB]
Fetched 7796 kB in 4s (1592 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 9bcb0285ff3f
 ---> 7fb346c1196b
Step 3/6 : RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in 6b42686c1c69
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libuv1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libuv1 nodejs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 3524 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libuv1 amd64 1.9.1-3 [84.4 kB]
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 nodejs amd64 4.8.2~dfsg-1 [3440 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 3524 kB in 1s (2250 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libuv1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 13068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuv1_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_4.8.2~dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Setting up nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/js.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz (of link group js) doesn't exist
Removing intermediate container 6b42686c1c69
 ---> cd6622204549
Step 4/6 : RUN nodejs -v
 ---> Running in 103bfc7b3396
v4.8.2
Removing intermediate container 103bfc7b3396
 ---> 978bd59b62df
Step 5/6 : RUN npm -v
 ---> Running in 9762ed0c24b4
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm -v' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Related: [node: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/a/405035/32996).

Comment: Also note that the nodejs provided by apt is *really* outdated, like 4 major versions behind the LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu, the node.js executable is named `nodejs`, not `node`

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN nodejs -v
```

---

```
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
 ---> 18747ca95580
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 416b334f6ea7
Step 3/6 : RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0606aac728ee
Step 4/6 : RUN nodejs -v
 ---> Running in c300e7140695
v4.8.2
```

You get a very old version of Node, however. You can try this alternative approach which installs [Node v8 (the current LTS)](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) via Node's repository

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gnupg2
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN nodejs -v
RUN npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: side note: you can reduce the number of layers by combing the different run commands into a single one

Comment: thanks! i noticed it was a very old version of node - would I be better getting / compiling from source? Will that also give me npm?

Comment: @Alex rather than compiling from source you're better off using node's repository as mentioned in my alternative approach. That does give you npm

Comment: So close! using that exact dockerfile, doesn't seem to install npm - I get an error saying it's not found. If I add `RUN npm -v` I get `/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found` - interestingly, the node version reports as `v4.8.2`

Comment: @Alex try the alternative approach

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - that is using the alternative approach

Comment: @Alex weird. can you try `docker build --no-cache .` ? Also please [edit] your question and add the contents of the Dockerfile and the output from running this?

Comment: The output doesn't match what the dockerfile has. Are you sure you've modified the right file in the right directory, @Alex

Comment: sorry, `RUN apt-get -y install build-essential` wasn't in the dockerfile when i ran it... hence step 3 missing. Removed that now (doesn't work with/without)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177588/discussion-between-alex-and-sathya).

Comment: Somewhat out of date but if anyone else finds this answer and gets this far the solution is to change `RUN apt-get install -y nodejs` to `RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm`.